# Override Go Method in Tests

Tags: unit-testing, oop, testing, go

So I have this `Client` struct that has a method `UserByID` that makes a HTTP request to an endpoint for a `User`. I want to unit test this function but also not make an actual HTTP request in the function `c.Request`. I want to stub that function with a response and error I can control.

```
func (c Client) UserByID(id string) (u User, err error) {
  v := url.Values{}
  v.Set("id", id)
  opts := Request{
    HTTP: http.Request{
        Method: http.MethodGet,
        Form:   v,
    },
    URL: 'some/endpoint/users',
  }
  resp, err := c.Request(opts)
  err = json.Unmarshal(resp, &u)
  return
}
```

Here's what the stub looks like:

```
type mockClient struct {
  Client
  fakeUser  User
  fakeError error
}

func (mc mockClient) Request(opts Request) (resp []byte, err error) {
  resp, err = json.Marshal(mc.fakeUser)
  err = mc.fakeError
  return
}
```

In a single test I have something like:

```
client := mockClient{
  fakeUser: User{},
  fakeError: nil,
}
user, err := client.UserByID(c.id)
```

Then I can assert the return values from `client.UserByID`. In this example I'm trying to override the `client.Request` function but I understand Go is not an inheritance-type of language. In my tests, my `mockClient.Request` function is not being called. The original `client.Request` is still being called.

I then assume that my approach is not right then. How can I test `client.UserByID` without actually calling the real `client.Request` function within it? Should the design of my methods be different?

Comment: Don't mock your method--mock the functions called by your method. So in this case, mock `c.Request()`--or mock the server it talks to (it's trivial in Go to start a test server that can send actual HTTP responses for your tests to consume).

Comment: A Java-esque attempt to unit testing is damned to fail in Go. Don't Do this. Either call an actual HTTP server (trivial) or separate this piece of functionality. Never even try traditional OOP techniques in Go, they all will fail.

Answer (score 12):

To accomplish what you need, you can re-structure your code just a little bit.

You can find a full working example here: https://play.golang.org/p/VoO4M4U0YcA

And below is the explanation.

First, declare a variable function in your package to encapsulate the actual making of the HTTP request:

```
var MakeRequest = func(opts Request) (resp []byte, err error) {
    // make the request, return response and error, etc
}
```

Then, in your `Client` use that function to make the request:

```
func (c Client) Request(opts Request) (resp []byte, err error) {
    return MakeRequest(opts)
}
```

In that way, when you actually use the client, it will make the HTTP request as expected.

But then when you need to test, you can assign a mock function to that `MakeRequest` function so that you can control its behaviour:

```
// define a mock requester for your test

type mockRequester struct {
    fakeUser  User
    fakeError error
}

func (mc mockRequester) Request(opts Request) (resp []byte, err error) {
    resp, err = json.Marshal(mc.fakeUser)
    err = mc.fakeError
    return
}

// to use it, you can just point `MakeRequest` to the mock object function

mockRequester := mockRequester{
    fakeUser:  User{ ID: "fake" },
    fakeError: nil,
}
MakeRequest = mockRequester.Request
```

Answer (score 2):

> **I then assume that my approach is not right then.**

Your description covers it Exactly!  Even though you're [embedding](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding) the `Client` in `mockClient` when you call `client.UserByID(c.id)` go looks at the `mockClient` and sees the method pulled up from `Client` . it ends up so that the `Client`!!! is the receiver to `UserByID` call NOT the `mockClient`. You can see this here:

`func (c Client) UserByID(id string) (u User, err error)`

Once the `Client` is the receiver  `resp, err := c.Request(opts)` is called with the `Client` receiver above and NOT your `mockClient` as you're observing.

---

One way to introduce a [seam](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=359417&seqNum=2) for `c.Request` that you can provide a custom implementation for use in unit testing is to make `Request` a callout method on your `Client` struct.

```
type Client struct {
    Request func(opts Request) (resp []byte, err error) 
}
```

The above should help to decouple Client from `Request` implementation.  All it says is that `Request` will be a function that takes some args with some return value, allowing you to substitute different functions depending if you're in production or testing.  Now during your public initialization of `Client` you can provide your real implementation of `Request`, while in unit tests you can provide your fake implementation.

```
type mockRequester struct {
  fakeUser  User
  fakeError error
}

func (mc mockRequester) Request(opts Request) (resp []byte, err error) {
  resp, err = json.Marshal(mc.fakeUser)
  err = mc.fakeError
  return
}

mr := mockRequester{...}
c := Client{  
  Request: mr.Request,
}
```

This comes with its own tradeoffs though as you potentially lose the client as a pointer receiver in your `Request` callout function.

Another cool part of the Callout is that it gives you another option of encapsulation.  Suppose in the future you'd like to provide some sort of exponential backoff or retry.  It would allow you to provide a more intelligent `Request` method to `Client` without `Client` having to change.